# formatting a dataframe in the console

Tags: python

can anyone explain why:

```
bal_sheet.style.format('${:,.2f}')
```

in jupyter notebooks generates a nicely formatted print out of the dataframe, but generates a AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'format' in pycharm?

related question suggests identifying each row and column you want to format.

is there a way to format the entire dataframe without listing the indices?

i tried using:

```
print(f'{bal_sheet:.2f}')
```

but got TypeError: unsupported format string passed to DataFrame.**format** error message.

how do you format the printout of a dataframe?

Comment: Where do you see that it says to list the rows and columns? Doing `pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.2f}'.format` affects the whole dataframe...

Comment: i used pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.2f}'.format and got back:                                         ProForma  ...              per_54
CashBal                          73844.723805042  ...       $1,197,770.69
Accts Rec. Balance                         $0.00  ...          $49,337.79
Inventory                             $15,000.00  ...          $59,536.73 and                          
Owners Equity                 103486.72380504198  ...  103486.72380504198.              
 don't understand why first column of Cash and all columns of Owner's equity aren't formatted.

Comment: Maybe the data there is actually string and not float?